# How to call a javascript inside xsl?

Tags: xslt

I want to call a javascript function inside a xsl like this :

```
<ParameterBinding Name="Segment" Location="None" DefaultValue="javascript :GetCurrentSegment()"/>
```

How do I do this ? Is it the correct way ?

Comment: You code as written just generates some Javascript code in the result document. If you want something executed to compute the DefaultValue attribute, you need to make it an XPath expression in curly braces. The XPath expression can be a call on an external function implemented in Javascript if you are using an XSLT processor that allows such calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I am trying to compute the DefaultValue attribute . Can you please elaborate more on how to call the javascript function using XPath ?

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? There are not many that support calling into Javascript and even when supported you have to understand that you have access to an ECMAScript 3 engine in most cases or perhaps a JScript.NET engine. But you won't have access to any browser object, like with Javascript in HTML.